# Create a list with class properties

Tags: c#

My class has some properties with base type and a dictionary as:

```
public class Statistic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public object Parent { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> DataDictionary { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public Statistic()
    {
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a list with all the properties' name and I did this:

```
                List<string> columns = new List<string>();

                PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Statistic).GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                    columns.Add(property.Name);
                    if (property.Name=="DataDictionary")
                    {
// How to iterate thru my Dictionary?
                    }
                }
```

How to iterate thru my dictionary?

Comment: first you need to retrieve the properties value:`property.GetValue(myInstance, null)`. Afterwards cast to the appropriate type, in your case `Dictionary<string, object>`. Then you should be able to iterate it.

Comment: Do you need refletion? It would be easier with a reference

Comment: Can't use directly use `DataDictionary`?

Comment: You want to iterate through properties of a dictionary, not through its items?

Comment: Yes I iterated directly to dictionary, thanks

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Using reflection can be dangerous, without more information it is hard to tell if it is a appropriate solution to whatever the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the `DataDictionary` and iterate like this.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in DataDictionary)
{
    // use the kvp.Value and kvp.Key
}
```